# Flowplayer 5.2: how to get time from event binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I am using jQuery to bind event listeners to Flowplayer 5.2 videos, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".flowplayer").each (function() {
        console.log("Got a flowplayer: " + $(this));
        $(this).bind("ready", function(event, api) {
            console.log("Flowplayer ready");
        }).bind("pause", function(event, api) {
            console.log("Flowplayer pause");
            var time = {?}.getTime();
            console.log("Time: " + time);
        });
     });
});
```

I'd like to get the current time/duration of the video when events such as pause occur. What should the `${?}` in the code above be replaced with?

I've tried replacing the `{$}` in the code above with `$(this)`, `$(this).getClip()`, `$f(0)`, and `$f()` and none of those worked. I'm wondering if I can get it off of the `event` or `api` parameters in the callback function, but I figured I'd ask instead of randomly trying to access parameters that don't exist.

I've been digging through all of the Flowplayer documentation I can find, but I haven't seen how to do this from a bound event handler (unless you're using a custom configuration and binding the events at config time as shown [here](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/events/google-analytics.html)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var time = api.video.time`

http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html#video-object

`console.debug(api.video)` helped me find it ...